# React clear modal input bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a list of users, clicking on the user allows you to edit the data about the user. Upon closing the bootstrap modal, I want to clear whatever the person has typed into input fields. Does anyone have any suggestions on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vanilla js:

```
document.querySelector('form').clear();
```

React way:

Assign a ref to the form as `this.form` and then:

```
this.form.clear();
```

EDIT:

You can check if a modal is open with this code:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.modal.in').length > 0;
```

Comment: How do you detect if the modal has been closed? Whats the react way of doing that?

Comment: It depends, what are you using for your modal? A package? Did you write it yourself?

Comment: Simple bootstrap Modal.

Comment: Are you using react-bootstrap or vanilla bootstrap?

Comment: vanilla bootstrap

Comment: Updated answer with how to check if the modal is open. Ideally though, you would put the `form.clear()` code in the `onSubmit` function of the form.